# Creating webView for C# / Mono Launcher

Tags: c#, html, css, webview

I develop a c# mono launcher via Xamarin Studio I want make the UI with HTML and CSS in a webView. Is something like this possible in C# and how can i do it?
Thanks for help.

Greetings Chryb

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the essence of hybrid apps - exposing html based UIs within a webview control.

You set the webview control url to target your html file.